# curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'hproxy.iitm.ac.in'

Tags: configuration, proxy, curl

I have been using the proxy `hproxy.iitm.ac.in`. I've moved out now and want to change config to no proxy. On using:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```

I'm prompted with:

```
curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'hproxy.iitm.ac.in'
```

I'm not very proficient with Ubuntu (using 12.10). Please, could someone tell me what configurations I need to change to be able to use curl?

**EDIT :** I'm able to browse internet. I have also changed my ~/.bashrc to show:

```
export http_proxy="";
export https_proxy="";
export ftp_proxy="";
```

But it didnt help

Thanks.

Comment: Just go to wherever you set the proxy before, and unset it. Do you remember? Click on the gears icon at the top right > System Settings > Network > Proxy, and see if the proxy is set. Let us know if you can already browse the internet normally, but `curl` still gives you the proxy error. Also, what is the output of `env | grep -i proxy`?

Comment: @Alaa : Yeah i've already changed that. but still getting the prompt. I'm able to browse internet.

Comment: @Alaa : env | grep -i proxy givea:



NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8
http_proxy=http://roll_num:password@hproxy.iitm.ac.in:3128
ftp_proxy=http://roll_num:password@hproxy.iitm.ac.in:port
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=libappmenu.so
https_proxy=http://roll_num:password@hproxy.iitm.ac.in:port
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8

Comment: i faced this when i was trying curl with option `-xget` instead of `-XGET`. silly me :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments and your output of `env`, you still have some proxy variables set. Execute the following commands to unset them:

```
unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Double check that they've been removed by:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

Now try your `curl` command.

Answer (score 5):

You can temporarily bypass the proxy by using the `--noproxy` option, e.g.

```sh
curl -L https://get.rvm.io --noproxy | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```

You may need to remove proxy settings in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or system wide(`/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` etc...). Also take a look at `~/.curlrc`.

> **NOTE**: if you are using GNOME Desktop Environment, you also need to unset the proxy in System Settings - Network.

Comment: He's asking how to remove the proxy, not to temporarily bypass it.

Comment: I tried the command. I'm getting "curl: option --noproxy: requires parameter
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"

Comment: Terry : I've changed my ~/.bashrac file to:
export http_proxy="";
export https_proxy="";
export ftp_proxy="";
But it didnt help. I'm getting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Open ~/.bashrc add these lines to unset variables.

```
export http_proxy="";
export https_proxy="";
export ftp_proxy="";
```

Then either logout and login from terminal or source .bashrc.